# PyClewn Failed to start error

Tags: terminal

I have been trying to get [PyClewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) to work by
following the instructions step by step without much luck. This is the error I
get when I type `:PyClewn` into vim:

```
Running nbstart, <C-C> to interrupt.
.'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/clewn/__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import vim
  File "clewn/vim.py", line 663
    self.nbserver = yield from(self.loop.create_server(protocol_factory,
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
..................
The 'Pyclewn' command has been aborted.
Error: pyclewn failed to start.
To get the cause of the problem set the global variable 'pyclewn_terminal' to:
:let g:pyclewn_terminal = "xterm, -e"
Press the <Enter> key to continue.
```

Also pyclewn won't work from terminal either and get's me this output:

```
 python -m clewn
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/clewn/__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import vim
  File "clewn/vim.py", line 663
    self.nbserver = yield from(self.loop.create_server(protocol_factory,
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried reinstalling but didn't fix it.

Comment: Check your python version, the plugin needs 2.7 or >=3.2

Comment: `Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)`
My Python version

Comment: if you do vim --version | grep python, is it compiled with 3 or 2? if it's compiled with 2 you need to check the version for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I found what the problem was. In the second output you see above that it goes to my python2.7 directory but the PyClewn was compiled/installed on my python3 directory and when I went to check to the Python2.7 directory there was nothing there and that's why it wouldn't run. 
Working fine now.